# Mapbox Changing Polygone Color based users area showed

Tags: mapbox

I'm currently building map using Mapbox GL. On this polygone there is polygone that are color based on 1 metric.
The metric range is between 1 to 25.

I have only 12 color panel.
[ColorPannel](https://i.stack.imgur.com/r1DPt.png)

The goals would be to

1. Retrieve to top left, top right, bottom left and bottom right of the users map screen.
2. Get all the polygone that fit into the area. (SQL request)
3. From all those polygone, I retrieve the metric MIN and MAX.
4. Create 12 range of value based of MIN and MAX.

How could I reload the color for each polygone showed on the map based on the 12 range of value that I received from the back-end. This reload of color need to be executed when the users stop moving the area.

Here is my sample of the code :

> ```
>    map.addLayer({
>         'id': 'terrain1-data',
>         'type': 'fill',
>         'source': 'level_hight',
>         'source-layer': 'sold_level_high-36rykl',             'maxzoom': zoomThresholdZoneHtM,            'paint': {
>           'fill-color': [
>               'interpolate',
>               ['linear'],
>               ["to-number",['get', 'MYMETRIC']],
>               0,
>               '#FFFFFF',
>               5,
>               '#008855',
>               6,
>               '#13be00',
>               7,
>               '#75e100',
>               8,
>               '#aee500',
>               9,
>               '#dfff00',
>               10,
>               '#fff831',
>               11,
>               '#ffe82f',
>               12,
>               '#ffd500',
>               13,
>               '#ffa51f',
>               14,
>               '#ff7b16',
>               15,
>               '#ff0a02',
>               16,
>               '#c80000'               
>           ],
>           'fill-opacity': [
>                 'case',
>                 ['boolean', ['feature-state', 'hover'], false],
>                 0.8,
>                 0.5
>             ],
>           'fill-outline-color': '#000000',
>                       }
>     });
> ```

Thanks in advance. Sorry I'm starting using Mapbox.

Answer (score 0):

If my understanding is correct, you want to set the number dynamically in 'interpolate'. In the following case you want to change 0, 5, ... according to the data, light?
'fill-color': [
'interpolate',
['linear'],
["to-number",['get', 'MYMETRIC']],
0,
'#FFFFFF',
5,

Then, normally you will get the date from your server and there's a chance to calculate those numbers in JavaScript code. Then put the calculated number in 'interpolate' would work.

Here's a sample. The number is generated randomly,

```
 map.on('load', function () {
    map.addSource('maine', {
        'type': 'geojson',
        'data': {
            'type': 'FeatureCollection',
            'features': [
                {
                    'type': 'Feature',
                    'geometry': {
                        'type': 'Polygon',
                        'coordinates': [
                            [[0, 0], [0, 1], [1, 1], [1, 0]]
                        ]
                    },
                    'properties': {
                        'height': 10
                    }
                },
                {
                    'type': 'Feature',
                    'geometry': {
                        'type': 'Polygon',
                        'coordinates': [
                            [[1, 1], [1, 2], [2, 2], [2, 1]]
                        ]
                    },
                    'properties': {
                        'height': 20
                    }
                },
            ]
        }
    });
    map.addLayer({
        'id': 'maine',
        'type': 'fill',
        'source': 'maine',
        'layout': {},
        'paint': {
            'fill-color': [
                'interpolate',
                ['linear'],
                ['to-number', ['get', 'height']],
                c(10),
                '#000000',
                c(10) + 10,
                '#FFFFFF',
            ]
        }
    });
});

function c(n) {
    return Math.round(Math.random() * n);
}
```